# Definition of Simple Functions

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Recently I came across an alternative definition for simple functions, namely that a function $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ on a measure space $(X, \mathcal{B})$ is simple if it only takes on a finite number of elements, i.e. for a set $\{a_1, \dots , a_n\} \subset \mathbb{R}$, we have that $f: X \rightarrow \{a_1, \dots , a_n\}$.

Looking at this, the definition above is equivalent to the standard definition:

> Let $A_1, ..., A_n ∈ \mathcal{B}$ be a sequence of disjoint measurable sets, and let $\{a_1, \dots, a_n\}$ be a set of real numbers. A simple function is a function $f: X \to \mathbb{R}$ of the form:
>
> $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k {\mathbf 1}_{A_k}(x)$

However, since the first definition is hardly ever used (only came across it in one book), I am wondering if there is something where you need to be careful or what is not ideal about using this definition.

Are they, for example, equivalent on $\mathbb{R}$ but not on a more general field?

I would very much appreciate your input.

Comment: These two definitions are equivalent on every measure space if you add the assumption that $f$ is measurable.

Comment: I believe that $f$ also needs to be measurable.  It doesn't matter what the measure space is for this. Do you see why the two definitions are equivalent?

Comment: @JairTaylor Thanks for adding the measurability condition. I very well see why they are equivalent. This gave rise to this question because I would expect the first one being used more often as it's the "shorter"/"easier" one (that's unobjective, obviously!).

Comment: I would say the reason it is defined this way is because it is more convenient for its intended purpose, which is defining integration.  If you have $f = \sum_k a_k 1_{A_k}$ then we have an easy formula for the integral: $\int f = \sum_k a_k \mu(A_k)$.  It's not quite as obvious from the alternate definition.